# Apache IP and name based virtualhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm not new to apache, but I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

**I can't get a 2nd VirtualHost up on a particular IP.** It seems to just use the default VirtualHost for that IP.

I have a server which owns two IP addresses. It runs on ports 80 and 443 on both IPs, such that I have four NameVirtualHosts e.g.

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443
NameVirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80
NameVirtualHost 2.2.2.2:443
```

Now I have a default (i.e. file is named such that it would be sourced before the next one) VirtualHost for 2.2.2.2:80 defined as

```
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ip2-80-access.log combined 
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ip2-80-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And a 2nd one

```
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    ServerName foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo.example.com
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ip2-80-access.log combined 
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ip2-80-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS is set up so that `foo.example.com` points to `2.2.2.2`.

But when I try to access `foo.example.com/anything` I get a 404 not found. It seems apache is ignoring my 2nd name-based and ip-based virtualhost.

I'm using Apache 2.2 on Debian 6 (Squeeze). Please note: I am **not** trying to get apache to choose a virtual host for SSL here (I am aware of limitations/SNI etc.), this is standard port 80.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apache2ctl -S` to list the virtualhosts and defaults.

This shows that apache is selecting **default** VirtualHost for this IP:Port as the one for the specified host name:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
2.2.2.2:80     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server foo.example.org.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/2.2.2.2:1)
         port 80 namevhost foo.example.org.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/2.2.2.2:1)
         port 80 namevhost foo.example.org.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/2.2.2.2:18)
2.2.2.2:443    is a NameVirtualHost
         ...
1.1.1.1:80     is a NameVirtualHost
         ...etc...
```

i.e. I had thought that because I was supplying a host name that matched a `VirtualHost`'s `ServerName` directive, and **not** supplying a `ServerName` in the default, that the 2nd one would be chosen.

However, what Apache seems to do is use the hostname for 2.2.2.2 from `/etc/hosts` as the hostname for **any** requests on that IP. This is a bit opaque IMO.

So 2 alternative ways to get it working:

1. change the hostname in `/etc/hosts` e.g. to `foo2.example.org.uk`. Restart Apache and now requests for `foo.example.org.uk/something` work. Of course, this is really proof of concept and you probably want your server name to match the main server name.
2. add a `ServerName` directive to the **first** `VirtualHost`. It can be anything, e.g. `goaway.local`. This will mean that requests on the proper domain name get served by the correct `VirtualHost` block an that anything else (e.g. all those annoying direct IP vulnerability probes) are handled by the default, which can be set to deny everything.

Comment: +1 for the useful apachectl command (didn't know about that).  However, I'm curious what is the point of that first/unused VirtualHost if you are not going to use it?  Side note:  I always setup my web/app servers as if it was a member in a cluster, so their hostnames will never match that of the site URL (so it would have been covered by alt 1).

Comment: Thanks. I was of the mindset at the time that it was cleaner/safer/easier to maintain the default as a No-no-go-away, and then to have the more general stuff in a nice clean separate virtual host. Actually I abandoned that and do now use the default one with a RewriteRule to check that the person acceseed it via the correct domain.